# links in Serverfault not readily visible

Tags: feature-request, design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change style of Links](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1745/change-style-of-links)

Please consider either changing the color of links in serverfault slightly to contrast more with regular text, or make the links underlined. It is nearly impossible to see them.

[example on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/83434/apache-logging-rotating-logs-on-win32)

Note that on this site the underlined link style is used.

Comment: Dotted underlines of a lighter colour really do look pleasant.

Comment: Yeah, agree here as well.  I always bold the links to make them more distinguishable.

Comment: my preference would be dotted underlines, with full underlines on mouse-hover

Comment: I was going to ask the same question but decided to search first (glad I did). I see this question was asked back in 2009. Any update on this?

Answer (score 2):

With reference to the example given, the link in one of the answers is quite prominent, but the link in the question is quite difficult to see due to the way it is presented, of course, this may vary from computer to computer, or from user to user due to various factors (eyesight, display properties, etc.)

I don't think it would hurt to tweak the colour slightly to make it a little less subtle, but *please* don't mess with the font weight or style.