# Inline HyperLink Color

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change style of Links](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1745/change-style-of-links)

I'm not sure about everyone else but I'm finding it hard to identify links in questions and answers, especially when the link text itself is very small.

The dark blue color looks very similar to the black default text.  Even links that appear in Meta are different and visible thanks to the underline.

It might be nice to change the color to the crimson color that most of the rest of the site uses to try and make it a bit more contrasting.  It just seems a bit too similar to me.

Anyone else having the same problem?

Comment: Yes, I struggle with this too and often miss links unless they're obvious.

Comment: [What is this futile agitation for readability?](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1745/change-style-of-links) - [BLASPHEMY I SAY!](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/262/links-in-serverfault-not-readily-visible) YOU'LL TAKE BLACK ON BLACK AND YOU'LL ***LIKE*** IT!

Comment: Well damn... for once the sidebar and suggested questions didn't show me that question.  Should we close this one as a dup?

Comment: I created a userstyle for use with sylish that 'fixes' this http://userstyles.org/styles/68486/serverfault

Answer (score -1):

Use [Stylish](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe?hl=en-GB) to change the colours then.